# How can i show the Count of Contributions in a give time period?

Tags: civicontribute

I checked the awesome [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) extension and the [Advanced Fundraising Reports](https://civicrm.org/extensions/advanced-fundraising-reports) one but neither seem to quite offer this.

I could do this as a Drupal View but that won't give me the full suite of 'Actions' that might be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did create additional Summary Fields to cover 1 Apr - Mar 31, and for July 1 - June 30. We then found out that by setting the Financial Year field in civicrm/admin/setting/date?reset=1 to the correct date had the desired outcome.

We therefore made a PR for the extension to improve the documentation to avoid this catching out others unaware.

Answer (score 0):

If Summary Fields does not have the fields you need, it's pretty easy to add your own using `hook_civicrm_sumfields_definitions()`

Try dropping something like this into an extension:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_sumfields_definitions().
 *
 */
function myextension_civicrm_sumfields_definitions(&$custom) {
  $custom['fields']['contribution_count_twelve_months'] = array(
    'label' => 'Count of Contributions in last 12 months',
    'data_type' => 'Int',
    'html_type' => 'Text',
    'weight' => '15',
    'text_length' => '32',
    'trigger_sql' => '(
      SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(id), 0) 
      FROM civicrm_contribution t1
      WHERE t1.contact_id = NEW.contact_id AND t1.contribution_status_id = 1 AND
      t1.financial_type_id IN (%financial_type_ids) AND 
      CAST(receive_date AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND NOW()
      )',
    'trigger_table' => 'civicrm_contribution',
    'optgroup' => 'fundraising',
  );
}
```

Tweak the `trigger_sql` for your preferred time interval.

See the [Readme](https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/blob/master/README.md) for more info.

Comment: Many thanks Aidan - this is the route we will likely go assuming there is nothing already around. Appreciate the effort put in to providing a useable answer